# How to put multiple checkboxes into a form with Apache Wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

I want to create a webpage that looks like this one:

[image: Table with multiple checkboxes]

This is done using a table. Each row describes an object and I want to be able to select multiple of those objects. When one of the submit-buttons is clicked, I want to get the list of selected objects. I know there is the class `CheckBoxMultipleChoice`, but the generated output is not what I need.

I think I should use a `ListView`, but since the number of objects is dynamic, I do not know how to access the states of the checkboxes. Could you please tell me how I can achieve this layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a CheckGroup with one Check component in each row.

Comment: http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/CheckGroup.html